# How to avoid wrong HTML Content which is written inside a td tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two column (say Name, Value).
The first column simply gives a name and the other column is a value. The value may be anything eg. a text, a number or an HTML Content.

The html content will appear in a **compiled** format, **not the code** format.
The issue arises when the  inside td tag is written in a wrong format, where  is written without its opening tag.
This kind of html content is breaking down my table and the next row onward contents are going out of the table. I know it's reason. It is simply because the broken html content's closing tag is combining its content with my master table.

How to resolve such issues.

My table is

```
<table id="master">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tr>
    <td> N1 </td>
    <td> ABC </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>N2</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>N3</td>
    <td>..HTML CONTENT...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>N4</td>
    <td>Anoter Value</td>
</tr>
```

And If Suppose **..HTML CONTENT...** is

```
            <ol>
                <li>x</li>
                <li>y</li>
                <li>z</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here **< /tr > < /td >** and **< /table >** is used without their appropriate opening tag. So this is grouping itself with master table's **< td > < tr >** and **< table >** and so breaking up the next row out of the table.

Please remember that **..HTML CONTENT...** is a content which is given by the outside user and that content has to be displayed in the master table's 2nd column's cell.

Comment: Do you want to clean up the broken parts from the code or do you want to repair it? What server side language creates the template?

Comment: You could not allow table related tags in the HTML, parse for them and remove, have an allowed set of tags for the HTML content.

Comment: Are you using WordPress, PHP...? Please elaborate!

Comment: If you have no control over what might end up in the td, you could add an an iframe inside the td, that way it will be rendered as it's own document.

Comment: Hi, I am using Html C# Razor Syntax to bring the data. The ..HTML CONTENT.. is populated from the database. I don't want such broken code to get mixed up with my master table code.